# Interpreting estimated parameter in Exponential Random Graph Model

Tags: logistic, inference, networks

I am estimating an [exponential random graph model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_random_graph_models) considering the following configurations:

- edges
- 2-stars
- 3-stars, and
- triangles

However, my edges parameter is estimated to be a negative value, while all other parameters have positive estimates. What is the interpretation of such a result? Can it be interpreted as the following?:

**While tendencies for centralization (seen in the formation of 2 stars and 3 stars) and triangulation are present, graphs with a large number of single ties are less likely.**

Answer (score 1):

The edge term in any ERGM is almost always negative. In the simplest terms, this means that ties are not likely formed at random. If you run a null model (i.e. network ~ edges), the edge term is equivalent to the density of the graph. Consider that the naive probability of observing a tie between any two nodes. As you add terms, they have more explanatory power regarding the formation of ties. So the edge term decreases. The star terms indicate clustering and preferential attachment, so edges are not distributed randomly and the probability of tie formation is not uniform across the network. Also, remember to exponentiate your terms to aid interpretation!